# Error in opening a signed S3 URL in a new window in an async operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button in a react component. On the click of the button, I make an API call to fetch a signed S3 url of a resource to download. Below is the relevant code

```
// inside render method
<Button onClick={() => getS3DownloadUrl('sample.zip')}>
    Download Sample
</Button>

// component method
getS3DownloadUrl(fileName) {
    let newWindow = window.open();
    axios.get("www.myapp.com/downloads/" + fileName).then(response => {
        newWindow.location = response.data;
    }).catch(error => {
        // handle error
    });
}
```

The above code works and Firefox show a download popup in a new tab to accept/cancel the download. On subsequent clicks, I get an error on the new tab (screenshot attached). However, when I refresh the tab, I get the download popup again so this means the URL is correct but I am not able to figure out the reason for the error in the first place. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before; Try this snippet by [javilobo8](https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743)

```
axios({
  url: "www.myapp.com/downloads/" + fileName,
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'blob', // important
}).then((response) => {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
});
```

Comment: Please note response.data is a URL and not the blob itself.

Comment: You could put that block instead of 
        newWindow.location = response.data;
window.open is almost always blocked by most browser's popup detection :(